# Finding the basis of all polynomials of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ such that $a+d = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Find the basis of all polynomials that satisfy $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ such that $a+d = 0$.

I rewrote this as $ax^3+bx^2+cx-a$ and I am now stuck there, my textbook does not mention anything about this and I have only found example online where they are given a value of $x$.  Perhaps someone could lead me in the right direction?

Comment: $\{(1,0,0,-1),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$ is the basis

Comment: @user130512 Provide your starting point - this would help the OP.

Comment: @user130512 Thank you for the answer, but I am looking for how to get there.

Comment: @Jtesuce Each $a$, $b$, $c$ in your equation will give you a vector in the basis, for example, the first position is $a$ and the last position is $-a$ so your vector is $(1,0,0,-1)$. You can check your answer by setting $av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ and seeing if they give you your polynomial as required.

Comment: @user130512: Not quote: what you wrote is the *coordinates* (relative to the power bases on the space of all polynomials) of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider the space of all polynomials of the form $$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d.$$ How do you find a basis for this space? Basically, you can just plug in linearly independent choices for $(a,b,c,d)$ to get a basis. There are many different bases, but probably the simplest ones is obtained by choosing $$(a,b,c,d) \in \{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}.$$ For instance, taking $(a,b,c,d) = (0,1,0,0)$ means taking $a = c = d = 0$ and $b = 1$ leading to the polynomial $x^2$. With these four "basis vectors" we then get the basis $$\{x^3, x^2, x, 1\}.$$ This is indeed a basis for the space of all polynomials of degree at most $3$.

Now consider your problem, with the restriction $a + d = 0$. You're halfway there, as you already noted that all such polynomials can thus be written in the form $$ax^3+bx^2+cx-a.$$
In other words, if I choose $a,b,c$, this gives me one of those polynomials. And each such polynomial belongs to one specific choice of $a,b,c$. So we now only have three parameters to choose. Again, there are many options for $a,b,c$ that lead to different bases, but the simplest one is arguably $$(a,b,c) \in \{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}.$$ Using these choices for our parameters, we get the basis $$\{x^3 - 1, x^2, x\}.$$

Comment: Thank you, this was the last piece that I needed, I think I understand now

Answer (score 0):

Just like $user130512$ said, try to write the polynomial as 
$$(a,b,c,-a)= a (1,0,0,-1)+ b (0,1,0,0)+ c (0,0,1,0)$$
So these vectors are linearly independent, and every polynomial of the form you have, can be written as a linear combination of these. So these vectors provide you the basis.
Now, can you tell what do those vectors mean?